# completion time of jobs based on CPU utilization in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, response, cpu

I am doing a simulation to see how can I lower the completion time of a job in Hadoop. The only thing that I know is the CPU utilization(because it is just a simulation). I know that higher CPU utilization means higher completion time. But I can not model the relationship between these two! Assuming I have CPU utilization in one server 35% and the completion time for the task "t" on that server is "c". What can I say about completion time of "t" if the CPU utilization was 70%?

Comment: Without running a profiler to determine the correlation, all you can realistically say about it is that the completion time will be the same as or lower than your trial at 35%. Why not just measure the runtime of t at 35% and again at 70%?

Comment: because I want to do scheduling based on that. It is like offline calculation.

Comment: Well if you assume that CPU utilization directly correlates with completion time, then `t(35%) = c` implies `t(70%) = c/2`, but that's a big assumption to make. You can't use hadoop at all for this? You'd really only need to run a handful of jobs to test the correlation.

Comment: Do you mean CPU Utilization caused by the task of intereset, or opposite - CPU utilization aside of this task?

Comment: I mean CPU utilization caused by the task